# How to bind to same class instance var JavaFX

Tags: bind, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX, trying to use bind like this:

```
public function newCircle() : Circle {
    Circle {        
        centerX: 1
        radius: bind (centerX / prm._iMaxPop)
    }
};
```

I get "Non-static variable centerX cannot be referenced from a static context."  Also tried using this.centerX with same result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can add a temporary variable "c" which must be explicitly typed:

```
public function newCircle() : Circle {
    var c : Circle = Circle {        
        centerX: 1
        radius: bind (c.centerX / prm._iMaxPop)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
function newCircle() : Circle {
   var xVal =1; 
    Circle {        
            centerX: xVal;
            radius: bind (xVal / prm._iMaxPop)
       }
    }
```

Comment: Really looking to reference a variable (possibly changing) within the class.  Helped to figure it out though.